# Match the array index accessors

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create an expression that finds the index accessor of a array representation.

E.g. "myarray[1][22][333]" for this string the expected result should be four groups: "myarray", 1, 22 and 333;

I can't make the expression to work with multiple dimensions, the expression must match from 1 dimention ("array[1]") to N dimensions ("array[1][2][3]...")

Comment: how about `myarray` in one group and the numbers inside `[]` in another group?

Comment: I'm kinda dumb with expressions... This is my attempt: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:?\[(\d+)+\])+

Comment: must it be a simple form of expression? if you allowed `myarr[arr1[0][arr2[1]][2]][3]`, i am afraid regex is not a right tool for you and i can explain why. if you restrict it to the simple form, there are solutions.

Comment: I need to use regular expression for security reasons, I can't use some scripting language to evaluate the condition, so I'm building my parser to evaluate simple expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
(^\w+|(?<!^)\G)\[*\K([^\[\]\n]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xL1fZ5/2)

Comment: Your expression works, has some empty matches, but I can treat them in the code... Thank you Avinash, this is the second time you help me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work
Edit missed one character:

```
([^][]+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/77)

Comment: `[^[\]]` could get rid of the `]` too.